# The hook `black` requires pre-commit version 2.9.2 but version 2.6.0 is installed

Tags: python, git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I am having trouble with pre-commit and black.

Everything worked fine until I cleared the cache with `pre-commit clean`. Now I always get the error

> The hook `black` requires pre-commit version 2.9.2 but version 2.6.0 is installed. Perhaps run `pip install --upgrade pre-commit

If I check my version I am running the latest pre-commmit version (v2.12.1). Also, if I run the recommended command, nothing changes and I get the same error. If I deactivate the `black` hook the error disappears, so I at least know it's a problem with black.

I tried changing version of black from `stable` to the most recent, but nothing helps.

Any ideas how I can do to troubleshoot this?

My pre-commit config:

```
  - repo: https://github.com/ambv/black
    rev: stable
    hooks:
      - id: black
        language_version: python3.8
        exclude: |
          (?x)(
              migrations/|
              config/|
              _build/|
              buck-out/|
              build/|
              dist/
          )
```

Help is greatly appreciated

Comment: any chance that this hook gets executed with a virtual env different from the one you access from your command line ? for example : is your main python version also `3.8` ?

Comment: Yes, I am having an environment activated. But I get the same error if I deactivate my environment. I also get the error when I deinstall pre-commit in my environment which is quite strange. And I get the error when I use no environment at all. My main python version is 3.8

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`rev: stable` is not a supported configuration -- when you run you'll also get a warning telling you exactly that:

```
$ pre-commit  run black --all-files
[WARNING] The 'rev' field of repo 'https://github.com/ambv/black' appears to be a mutable reference
(moving tag / branch).  Mutable references are never updated after first install and are not
supported.  See https://pre-commit.com/#using-the-latest-version-for-a-repository for more details.
Hint: `pre-commit autoupdate` often fixes this.
...
```

the warning also tells you the rationale for this and explains the behaviour you saw: **mutable references are never updated after first install** -- so the version in your cache was from an old old version of black and when you cleared it that got updated to the latest

the latest version of black uses `types_or` in its definition which requires a newer version of `pre-commit`

an aside, your `exclude` isn't doing what you want -- `pre-commit` only runs on files which are checked into your repository so excluding things like `dist` and `_build` isn't necessary

to fix the actual error message you're seeing, make sure to `pip install --upgrade pre-commit` (and ~potentially `pre-commit install` to reset the git hooks if you've moved where pre-commit was installed from the first time) -- `which -a pre-commit` can help you locate all of your installations

---

disclaimer: I am the creator of pre-commit

Comment: Thank you very much Anthony! I wasn't aware `stable` was not supported as config. Updating the rev to the newest version and doing a `pre-commit install` did the trick. I thought a `pre-commit clean` would already reset the hooks, but it's good to know this is done via `pre-commit install`. Again, thank you for your support, quite amazing to receive help directly from the creator! And thank you for the great product :)

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and the other answer did not work for me.

I fixed it by uninstalling the old `pre-commit` that I had installed with `snap` and installing a new `pre-commit` with `conda`:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pre-commit
```